# How can I turn this dynamic query into a procedure or function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-queries

I have a dynamic query that pulls from a list of tables with the names of those stored in another table but I would like to be able to use the resulting set in another query.

```
declare @t table( tablename varchar(50)) 
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = ''

insert into @t
SELECT t.svc_table AS table_name FROM svc_defs AS t

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'Select convert(varchar(5),svc_defs.svc_id) as svcid, data_id, crid, d_custid, d_active From ' + tablename + 
' inner join svc_defs on svc_defs.svc_table = ' + '''' + tablename + '''' + ' union ' from @t 

--remove the trailing 'union'
Select @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 6)

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: You can't use dynamic SQL in a function... and you can put that SQL directly into a stored procedure. What exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: You can;t make this a function, but you could make a procedure for it. What have you tried? I guess the real question is why do you have a bunch of identical tables in the first place? Sounds like you have normalization issues. Also `SELECT @sql = @sql +` is undefined behaviour and can cause unintended results, instead use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` to aggregate. And you need to quote those table names using `QUOTENAME`. It's unclear why you need a table variable. Object names should be stored in data type `sysname` and dynamic SQL should be store in `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: I guess I need to clarify what this does: I have a list of tables stored in svc_defs. Each table has identical fields. The number of those tables may change at any moment so the query needs to be dynamic. What I really want to do is be able use the resulting set in a subsequent join but I cannot figure out how to do that. I should also, probably, mention that this is MS SQL 2005.

Comment: _I should also, probably, mention that this is MS SQL 2005_ Yes you should and you should also know that this is completely obsolete and unsupported and a giant security risk. The short answer is you cannot define any code "unit" that will accomplish your goal as stated. You cannot use a stored procedure within a SELECT query. Either store that resultset temporarily or use a completely dynamic approach. Alternatively fix your schema - tables of the same structure are a sign of improper normalization.

Comment: And learn the very significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL. By default, you should use UNION ALL until you have identified a need for duplicate removal.

Comment: I should know that 2005 is old and risky and I do, however, I have reasons to run that version. The question was not about what environment I should be running in - it was about a specific problem I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create scalar user defined function, which returns the sql statement.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GenerateSelectQuery() 
Returns nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @t table( tablename SYSNAME) 
declare @sql Nvarchar(max)

set @sql = ''
insert into @t
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME AS table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'Select convert(varchar(5),svc_defs.svc_id) as svcid, data_id, crid, d_custid, d_active From ' + tablename + 
' inner join svc_defs on svc_defs.svc_table = ' + '''' + tablename + '''' + ' union ' from @t 

--remove the trailing 'union'
Select @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 6)

RETURN @sql
END
```

you can call it as

```sql
declare @sqlstmt NVARCHAR(max) =  dbo.udf_GenerateSelectQuery()
SELECT @sqlstmt
```

or as

```sql
declare @sqlstmt NVARCHAR(max) 
SET @sqlstmt = (SELECT dbo.udf_GenerateSelectQuery())
SELECT @sqlstmt
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked great for me. I ended up using a temp table as suggested above with this scalar udf.

Comment: @SamRozenfeld, please mark it as answer, so it will be helpful for others in future.