# Databricks SQL UDF to define maximum date in table

Tags: sql, databricks, user-defined-functions

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am looking for a way how to create a SQL UDF that will return the maximum date of a column in a table.

Example:   Max_date(table1)

All our tables have a column named snapshotdate or snapshot_date.

I tried some stuff myself but I came to the conclusion that it might not be possible create a UDF that returns a value only by putting the table name in it as given in the example. I am not sure and just want need to know if it is possible or not.

Comment: This question ist already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888997/how-can-i-turn-this-dynamic-query-into-a-procedure-or-function.
Maybe it is helpful for others to share some code.

Comment: That link is not databricks, it's T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks SQL, you cannot directly pass a table name as an argument to an UDF to dynamically reference columns from different tables.UDFs in Databricks SQL are generally meant for transforming values.

However, if you want to get the maximum date from a specific column across different tables that have the same column name (snapshotdate or snapshot_date), you can achieve this using regular SQL queries without a UDF.

For example:

```
SELECT
  MAX(snapshotdate) AS max_snapshot_date
FROM
  table1;

SELECT
  MAX(snapshot_date) AS max_snapshot_date
FROM
  table2;
```

You would need to execute such queries separately for each table you want to retrieve the maximum date from.

If you want to automate this process and get the maximum date from multiple tables in a more programmatic way, you might need to use a programming language like Python to generate and execute these queries dynamically based on a list of table names.

OR as a second solution, you can use a view to simplify the process of getting the maximum date from different tables in Databricks SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MaxSnapshotDateView AS
SELECT
  'table1' AS table_name,
  MAX(snapshotdate) AS max_snapshot_date
FROM
  table1
UNION
SELECT
  'table2' AS table_name,
  MAX(snapshot_date) AS max_snapshot_date
FROM
  table2;
```

then you can query your view by selecting all etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was afraid of that and am aware of the examples you gave. I was able to create something in Pyspark but we want to create an easy and well performing way for end users to see what the latest snapshot date in a table is. This is why it has to be done in SQL. The examples you gave may result in a long processing time for tables with >10m records. Nevertheless, Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, an observation.

You can create spark UDF's that generate dynamic strings. You just can't create one that can execute that string.

```
# define a python function
def GetMax(tablename: str) -> str:
    sql = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM " + tablename
    df=spark.sql(sql)
    return sql
  
# register it so SQL can see it
spark.udf.register("GetMax", GetMax)
```

> RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063

This makes sense I guess because it's trying to register and run the function on individual workers so it doesn't make sense that 4 workers should all run an identical query. I can't help but think there is a way to do this, just don't know how. It would be awesome if a spark expert could chime in on a way to make this work.

Going back to the original requirement of *we want to create an easy and well performing way for end users to see what the latest snapshot date in a table is*

There are some other solutions I can think of:

1. Put it in a databricks dashboard that runs regularly (although maybe this value is dynamic enough that you have to run it very frequently)
2. Put it in a notebook that takes a parameter and call the notebook. The notebook has all the boring boilerplate guts

Just on the `union all` approach mentioned above, a smart query planner should know not to run all the other redundant selects if you run `SELECT max_snapshot_date FROM MyView WHERE table_name = 'table1'`. I don't know if databricks worls that way. Most versions of SQL certainly do.